# Swift protocol as generic type

Tags: swift

I have this kind of code:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
}

class P1: MyProtocol {
}

class P2: MyProtocol {
}

class C <T: MyProtocol> {
}
```

Then i need to define a variable to delegate all kinds of `C<MyProtocol>`:

```
var obj: C <MyProtocol>
```

But compile error comes:

**Using 'MyProtocol' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'MyProtocol' is not supported**

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
class C <T: MyProtocol> { }
```

Means that `C` is a generic class that can specialize on any type `T` that *conforms to* `MyProtocol`.

When you declare:

```
var obj: C <MyProtocol>
```

You are (I think) trying to say that the var `obj` will be an instance of `C` specialized to some type that conforms to `MyProtocol`,but you can't specialize a generic class on a protocol type, because there is no such thing as a direct concrete instance of a protocol. There can only be instances of a type *conforming* to the protocol. And there can theoretically be many different types that conform to the protocol. So that notation doesn't really tell the compiler which specific specialization of `C` to use.

This shouldn't be a problem though, because you can write things like:

```
var obj: C<P1> = C<P1>()
```

or

```
var obj = C<P2>()  // type is inferred
```

And within your class `C` you can still treat any uses of `T` as conforming to `MyProtocol`. So I think this should give you everything you need, as long as you remember that an instance of a generic class must be specialized to a single specific concrete type, not a protocol which could represent many possible concrete types.

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't need to declare type for a Swift's variable. The compiler can infer type in most cases. Also, for generic class, you should let the compiler figure out what the generic classes resolve to:

```
class C<T: MyProtocol> {
    var value: T

    init (value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

var obj = C(value: P1()) // type: C<P1>
// or:
var obj = C(value: P2()) // type: C<P2>
```

Comment: thank you for your respond, I need a array to store the class C's instances. var array = [C<MyProtocol>](),  but this also gets compile error.  How can I do this?